# Why do i get in the Date arrivalMuseum +7 Hours?

Tags: java, datetime

When i bring time from ZonedDateTime to Date I get the time increased exactly 7 hours in arrivalMuseum. What is the reason?

```
public static String determine(final String departureTime, final String city)
            throws ParseException {



        final ZoneId leavingZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Minsk");
        final ZonedDateTime departure = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime),
                leavingZone);

        final ZoneId arrivingZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        final ZonedDateTime arrival = departure.withZoneSameInstant(arrivingZone).plusMinutes(270);

        final Instant instant = arrival.toInstant();
        final Date arrivalMuseum = Date.from(instant);
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to get a `Date` object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help me and us to help you if you give an example of method arguments and desired and observed return value. And I agree with @MCEmperor that you shouldn’t use `Date` unless this is a strict requirement from somewhere.

Comment: What is the default JVM time zone (the default time zone of your computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason why `Date` is only compatible with the `Instant` class of the java.time package. This is because it only deals with the date in your personal timezone.

So when you print the `arrivalMuseum` object it gets automatically converted to whatever timezone you are currently in. Given the time difference of 7 hours this is probably `UTC+8`.

If you really need to use the old API you will need to use the `Calendar` api to get a date formatted for a specific timezone, but there are reasons a new date/time API was created and dealing with other timezones is one of them.